# How to use PHP to get all the image filenames except containing certain words?

Tags: php, regex

I like to use PHP to get all the filenames in a directory except if the filename contains a certain word, for example "thumbnail".

This is how I get all the image filenames:

```
$images = glob($imagesDir . $albumName . '/' . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
```

So I tried:

```
$images = glob($imagesDir . $albumName . '/' . '^(?!thumbnail$).*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
```

Apparently it would not return anything. I am not familiar with regular expression in PHP. Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`preg_grep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) you can use regular expression to exclude files that contain "thumbnail" ..

```
$images = array_values(preg_grep('/^(?!.*thumbnail).*$/', glob($imagesDir . $albumName . '/' . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions that only match strings not containing words [can be a bit difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word), and often inefficient too. Using a combination of regex and PHP might be the best option for you. Something like this should do:

```
$images = glob($imagesDir . $albumName . '/' . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
$images = array_filter($images, function($s) { return strpos($s,'thumbnail') === false; });
```

Also, my sincerest apologies for making the first part of my answer rhyme more than intended.

Comment: Hi I tried this method and when I echo $images, I still get thumbnail.jpg. I suspect that is because I haven't update the new filtered $images. If so, how do I accomplish that?

Comment: @AeroWindwalker ah, my apologies—I just edited it, that version should work for you.