# Using glob() to fetch filenames without "v[0-9]"

Tags: php, regex, glob, scandir

I know how to use `glob()` to fetch all image files in a directory, but I want to save retrieval time and only fetch the ones I need in the first place.

I am building a car dealership website, and there is a directory where all the vehicle photos get stored. Photos that are associated with a vehicle for sale start with the letter "v" and then the database ID, and then a dot before the model of vehicle.

Here is a sample list of files in a directory:

```
v313.2014.toyota.camry.0.jpg
v313.2014.toyota.camry.1.jpg
fordfusion.jpg
fordfusion2.jpg
v87.2015.honda.civic.0.jpg
v87.2015.honda.civic.1.jpg
2014.ford.escape.0.jpg
2014.ford.escape.1.jpg
```

Out of those files, only `fordfusion.jpg`, `fordfusion2.jpg`, `2014.ford.escape.0.jpg`, `2014.ford.escape.1.jpg` should be returned by `glob()`.

I hope this is possible without retrieving all the image files and then going through the array with a regex because 90% of the images being fetched wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: this may be of help. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24795467/2206004

Answer (score 1):

> I hope this is possible without retrieving all the image files and then going through the array with a regex because 90% of the images being fetched wouldn't be necessary.

Unless there is an *extremely* large number of files in the directory, this isn't worth worrying about. `glob()` internally has to iterate through all files in the folder to check their names against the pattern anyway; doing it in PHP code with a regular expression will perform equally well.

If there really is a very large number of files in the directory… don't do that. Large directories perform very poorly in general, and many filesystems have limits on the number of files in a folder. (For instance, the ext3 file system, common on older Linux systems, has a limit of around 32,768 files in a single directory.) Split them up into multiple directories.

To answer the question directly, though, there is no way to do this with a `glob()` pattern. It's possible to match all the files that *do* have names starting that way, but there's no way to invert the match. (You could check for `[^v]*` and `v[^0-9]*` as two separate patterns, but there's no way to combine them into a single pattern.)

Answer (score 0):

if you're confident that files you don't want to retrieve starts with the letter `v` or starts with `v` followed by any `digit` you can try use the following regex

```
^[^v]+$|^v[^\d].+
```

check the [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zD4aY8/2)